# Exponent of an Exponential Operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, taylor-expansion

There is a problem in my textbook that asks me to prove the following:

For a bounded operator $A$ on a Hilbert space, prove that:

$$(e^A)^n = e^{An} $$
for any natural number, $n$.

However upon expanding each exponential into their Taylor series, I find the lowest-powered terms to be $A^n$ and $A$, respectively, assuming that $e^{An} = e^B$ where $B = (nI)A$, $I$ being identity.

Am I wrong about the lowest-powered terms, or am I right, and missing the connection between the two.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For bounded operator we know that $e^Ae^B=e^{A+B}$ if $A,B$ commute. You can prove this developing the product of the series with the [Cauchy rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product#Cauchy_product_of_two_power_series), and than using the binomial formula that holds if $A,B$ commute

$$
e^Ae^B=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{A^i}{i!}\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{B^j}{j!}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\sum_{l=0}^{k}\frac{A^lB^{k-l}}{l!(k-l)!}=
$$
$$
=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k!}\sum_{l=0}^{k}\frac{k!}{l!(k-l)!}A^lB^{k-l}= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k!}(A+B)^k= e^{A+B}
$$

So, since $A$ commute with all powers $A^n$ we have
$$
(e^A)^2=e^Ae^A=e^{A+A}=e^{2A}
$$
and, by induction:
$$
(e^A)^n=e^A(e^A)^{n-1}=e^Ae^{(n-1)A}=e^{nA}
$$

Answer (score 1):

You are wrong.  $e^A = I + A + \ldots$, so $(e^A)^n = (I + A + \ldots)^n = I + n A + \ldots$.